# When using Oracle APEX , what is location for managing data using a webpage?

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm curious about how to use Oracle APEX. Is there a way to manage the data I put there(say in a sample table "Employees" ) via an external web page ?

So far , I [found this site regarding how to implement a web service](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/web_serv.htm#HTMAD006)

Sorry if this is a little vague, I'm new to apex and have no idea where to start. 
any tips appreciated, thanks

Comment: Oracle APEX lets you build web-based applications.  What is the "external web page" in this scenario?  Why wouldn't that simply be a page in your APEX application?  You certainly can implement a web service.  I'm just not sure that's what you want to do.

Comment: @JustinCave - In my case I believe I need to have some external page. Because the bigger picture is that we are migrating from some proprietary financial system into Oracle Financials (both in the cloud). I need to study up some more I think

Comment: It's certainly possible that you want to implement a web service.  But APEX happily produces web pages (for whatever definition of "external" you'd like to use).  APEX can be used to customize your Oracle apps so I'd expect that you could use it in the cloud to enhance your Oracle Financials app in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you give more details abou your needs
oracle apex is a flexible platform on integration with its oracle infrastructure

if you are new to it, for seeing its standalone capability you can check examples in oracle web site or  internet

for integration of it to third party systems you can use different methods like

1 you can embed a third party web page to your application by using iframe code structure like below
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2622038?start=0&tstart=0

2 or you can use javascript for poping up a third party site when an action occurs like pressing a button

3 for authentication you can use LDAP integrations and find details by doing a search at internet by using `oracle apex custom authentication schema`

4 for getting data from third party service you can use web services as you find

5 for publishing data from apex to other system you can use REST interface

6 for single sign on mechanism you can use oauth mechanism

etc.

Comment: My next goal is to create an application which is calling the database (just a simple SELECT from a bank-end Oracle cloud), and then show something interactive

Comment: as a fast track begining you may try the section 7 and 25.3 or 25.4 of https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/toc.htm depending on banks api interfaces